# min-cpu-platform for n2d-standard machine types not showing available from api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Per documentation n2d should be available in us-central1-a but its not showing up as an available cpu platform.

Documentation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available

```
$ gcloud beta compute zones describe us-central1-a
availableCpuPlatforms:
- Intel Cascade Lake
- Intel Skylake
- Intel Broadwell
- Intel Haswell
- Intel Ivy Bridge
- Intel Sandy Bridge
creationTimestamp: '1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-08:00'
description: us-central1-a
id: '2000'
kind: compute#zone
name: us-central1-a
region: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/gchips-cloud-infra-224518/regions/us-central1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/gchips-cloud-infra-224518/zones/us-central1-a
status: UP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zones subcommand doesn't appear to list available machine types. To confirm that those machine types are available in that zone, you could use the `machine-types` [subcommand](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/machine-types):

```
$ gcloud compute machine-types list | grep 'us-central1-a | grep n2d'
n2d-highcpu-16    us-central1-a              16    16.00
n2d-highcpu-2     us-central1-a              2     2.00
...
etc
```

It's not elegant, but it will work. Seems like machine types aren't "associated" with zones like CPU Platforms are, in Google's eyes.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for asking this question!

EDITED TO ADD:
Thanks for posting the error message you were getting! I recommend adding that to your question text so that a) others facing this error will find this thread and b) people trying to help have as much information as possible. Now that I understand the actual scope of the error, I believe the ACTUAL answer to your issue is this:

Although Rome may be a totally valid CPU platform within us-central1-a, it is not considered a valid candidate for *minimum* CPU Platform. You can find a list of supported minimum CPU platforms [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform).

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, but the reason why I was looking for the min-cpu-platform is because I am running into an issue trying to terraform an n2d-standard-96 machine type.

Getting the following error.

```
Error: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.minCpuPlatform': 'rome'. Invalid CPU platform., invalid
 
  on ../../modules/vm/main.tf line 105, in resource "google_compute_instance" "_":
 105: resource "google_compute_instance" "_" {
```

Comment: AH, this is also a Terraform question, then! I'm going to add the terraform tag to your question so that maybe it attracts more TF helpers - because just because something is available in the core of GCP, that doesn't mean that it's available as part of the provider yet.

Comment: @idiego209, I've updated my answer to reflect the actual question AND likely solution. hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you leaving min-cpu-platform blank resolved the issue.